# Datetime objects set to dict list

Tags: python, datetime

```py
#recalculate start and end datetime
current_datetime = self.start_datetime
counter = -1
for schedule_item_final in schedule_items_final:
    counter += 1            
    schedule_items_final[counter]["start_datetime"] = copy.deepcopy(current_datetime)
    schedule_items_final[counter]["end_datetime"] = copy.deepcopy(current_datetime) + timedelta(seconds=schedule_item_final["duration_milliseconds"]/1000)
    current_datetime += timedelta(seconds=schedule_item_final["duration_milliseconds"]/1000)
    print(current_datetime)
        
for schedule_item_final in schedule_items_final:
    print(schedule_item_final["start_datetime"])
```

I have this code my when i run it in console i saw something like this:

```
2023-04-24 13:07:14.931000
2023-04-24 13:08:40.953000
2023-04-24 13:10:06.975000
2023-04-24 13:11:32.997000
2023-04-24 13:12:59.019000
2023-04-24 13:14:25.041000
2023-04-24 13:15:51.063000
2023-04-24 13:17:17.085000
2023-04-24 13:18:43.107000
...
2023-04-24 15:03:42.095000
----------------------
2023-04-24 12:41:45.917000
2023-04-24 15:03:42.095000
2023-04-24 15:03:42.095000
2023-04-24 15:03:42.095000
2023-04-24 15:03:42.095000
2023-04-24 15:03:42.095000
2023-04-24 15:03:42.095000
2023-04-24 15:03:42.095000
2023-04-24 15:03:42.095000
2023-04-24 15:03:42.095000
2023-04-24 15:03:42.095000
...
2023-04-24 15:03:42.095000
```

where 2023-04-24 12:41:45.917000 is the self.start_datetime and 2023-04-24 15:03:42.095000 is the expected start_datetime of last list item.

What wrong with the above code?

Comment: What did you expect to see?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?   It isn't clear from your post.

Comment: I expect to see the start_datetime to grow +duration_milliseconds of schedule_item.

Comment: I'm not following how you are seeing that in your console when ```schedule_item_final``` would be the counter.

Comment: but it doesn't. looks like datetime object is muttable (but it doesn't).

Comment: Could it be that the value of `schedule_items_final[counter]` is the same dictionary object for different values of `counter`? How did you construct `schedule_items_final`?

Comment: schedule_items_final is a list of dictionaries. Each dictionary has key duration_milliseconds which represents the duration of each sound track.

Comment: Code editted...

Comment: This `for schedule_item_final in schedule_items_final:` smells for me.

Comment: @ChrisP are all your tracks intended to be exactly 86.022 seconds long? If not, I suspect that multiple items in `schedule_items_final` are in fact the same dictionary object.

Comment: For example, if you started by doing something like `schedule_items_final = [{}] * len(tracks)` you'd get into this situation.

Comment: @slothrop yes each schedule_item_final dict objects are copy of the first item, but don't worry about.

Comment: @ChrisP but are they copies? or are they the same object? For example, is it true that `id(schedule_items_final[0]) == id(schedule_items_final[1])` ? That would be true if they are the same object, false if they are copies.

Comment: they are copies, they are copied 100 times using copy.deepcopy.

Comment: I think that doesn't related somehow to start datetimes.

Comment: id(schedule_items_final[1]) == id(schedule_items_final[2]) has true result, so that's the problem.

Comment: There was an error in: `for i in range(1,absolute_time):
      item_copy = copy.deepcopy(schedule_item_main)
      item_copy["type"] = "one-time"
      schedule_items_final.append(schedule_item_main)`. It should be `schedule_items_final.append(item_copy)` now works.